# Unable to access SPAN class using prev, prevAll or closest

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a bizarre problem.

Please find my markup here:

```
<div class="box" id="1">
    <h2>Three Days at the Movies (MOV)</h2>
    <div class="subtitle">
        <div class="slots">
            <h3>Count: <span class="in"></span> of <span class="total">30</span></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="leader">B Jesus</div>
    </div>
    <ul class="ui-sortable" style="height: 120px;"><li data-flags="0" id="524">
    <div class="left">Becky Jesus <span>(Vipers)</span></div>
    <div class="right">
        <span class="first">MOV</span>
        <span class="second">MAD</span>
        <span class="third">TTC</span>
        <span class="fourth">BEA</span>
        <span class="fifth">DOG</span>
        <span class="flags good">0</span>
    </div>
</li><li data-flags="1" id="1146">
    <div class="left">Tyler Jesus <span>(11JC)</span></div>
    <div class="right">
        <span class="first">MOV</span>
        <span class="second">MAD</span>
        <span class="third">TTC</span>
        <span class="fourth">BEA</span>
        <span class="fifth">DOG</span>
        <span class="flags good">1</span>
    </div>
</li><li data-flags="15" id="1093">
    <div class="left">James Jesus <span>(11JC)</span></div>
    <div class="right">
        <span class="first">MOV</span>
        <span class="second">MAD</span>
        <span class="third">DOG</span>
        <span class="fourth">BEA</span>
        <span class="fifth">TTC</span>
        <span class="flags bad">15</span>
    </div>
</li></ul>
</div>
```

I have been using the following code to count the number of LI elements in my UL, then display it in `h3 > span.in`. The code also does a number of other things relevant to the drag/drop sortable effects provided by jQuery UI Sortable but I don't think they're important or getting in the way.

```
$('ul').each(function() {
    var $count = $(this).prev('.slots').children('.in');
    var $total = $(this).prev('.slots').children('.total');
    var elements = $(this).children('li').length;
    $count.text(elements);

    if( parseInt( $count.text() ) > parseInt( $total.text() ) )
        $count.addClass("exceeded");
    else
        $count.removeClass("exceeded");
    var rowHeight = 20;

    if( $(this).children('li:first').height() )
        rowHeight = $(this).children('li:first').height();

    var height = ((elements+3) * rowHeight);
    $(this).css("height",height);

    //  Re-sort, order by flags
    var $ul = $(this),
        $li = $ul.children('li');
    $li.sort(function(a,b){
        var an = parseInt( a.getAttribute('data-flags') ),
            bn = parseInt( b.getAttribute('data-flags') );
        if(an > bn) {
            return 1;
        }
        if(an < bn) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    });
    $li.detach().appendTo($ul);
});
```

I can't access the correct `span` to update. I've tried `prev` and `prevAll`, as well as `closest`. I can access the `subtitle` DIV and `slots` DIV, but I can't access the `h3` or `span` elements within the latter.

The strange thing is, I *swear blind* that this code was working when I looked at it two months ago. Now, it doesn't at all.

jsFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/7t6y8av0/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normal, because of the prev element is `.subtitle`, so if you want to access on `.slots`, use the following method:

```
var $count = $(this).prev().find('.slots .in');
```

Comment: Also worth nothing that `.children(".in")` won't work even after finding `.slots` because `.slots` has only one `<h3>` child, so you'd need to use `.find` from there

Comment: or only `.find(".slots .in")`

Comment: That's the ticket :) Thank you. I'm just so confused because honestly I'm sure this worked the last time I looked...............!

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```js
var $count = $(this).parent('.box').find('.in');
var $total = $(this).parent('.box').find('.total');
```

You an even create a wrapper variable so that you can use it without searching  the dom each time.

```js
var wrapper = $(this).parent('.box');
var $count = wrapper.find('.in');
var $total = wrapper.find('.total');
```

This way you can use the .box wrapper to find any subelement you need with no problems.